# Extraneous non-emits event listeners (deleteComponent) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Hello I have problem with emiting event from my child component to parent but just with this one for some reason other ones work perfectly and with "same" code.

Here is the code

Child component:

```
    emits: ['close', 'delete-component'],
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit('close');
        },
        deleteMethod() {
            this.$emit('delete-component',this.index);
        }
    },
```

Parent Component:

```
<SmallModal :index="ComponentToDelete" :show="DeletingComponent" 
@delete-component="deleteComponent($event)" @close="DeletingComponent = false">
</SmallModal>
```

FYI: I tried changing naming to various types its not that.

This is the error message:

[Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (deleteComponent) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out why this problem was happening, theres jetstream package that I was using in the modal also called jet-modal and it seems like it is not up to date with vue so I had to make my custom delete modal that pops up, now it works.